# how to fix unsupported ssl protocol error?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I am trying to add an advertiser link(paved.com) in my newsletter. Before adding to newsletter, I had to add that link to my custom domain, for that they (paved.com) had provided me with CNAME and it's value.
I add that to my DNS server, I am using aws's route53 as my dns server, so adding that was straightforward. But now, when I click on that link, it throws an `unsupported protocol error` i.e. `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

I have no clue how to debug this and I will really appreciate your time and help.

One thing I had tried was to issue a new certificate for the custom domain they had provided, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly the error happens when the web browser and the web server don’t support a common SSL protocol version.

Did you check the tls version? try to force the tls version to 1.2 and have a try.

Comment: how do i check the tls version? I try to check in the browser, but the lock icon doesn't appear beside the url

Comment: To get a better understanding of what causes this error, run the website through [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and test it for potential vulnerabilities. If the error is not related to the protocol verision, it could be a deprecated RC4 Cipher. Also check the linked guide on other possible causes and fixes of this particular [SSL error](https://www.ssldragon.com/how-to/fix-ssl-errors/err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch/).